# Join dataframe which share column names and some character strings

Tags: r, dplyr

I have what appears to be a simple join or merge of dataframes. Both dataframes share columns and some rows.

When using full_join the columns are matched but the shared rows are not being joined.

I have the following dummy code:

```
a<- c('x1', 'x2',   'x3',   'x4')
b<- c(12,   18, 11, 14)
c<- c(15,   23, 40, 43)
d<- c(0.2,  0.3,    NA, NA)

n1<-data.frame(a,b,c,d)

a<- c('x3', 'x4')
d<- c(1.1,  1.0)

n2<-data.frame(a,d)

n3<-full_join(n1,n2)
```

I got the following:

```
a   b   c   d
x1  12  15  0.2
x2  18  23  0.3
x3  11  40  NA
x4  14  43  NA
x3  NA  NA  1.1
x4  NA  NA  1
```

But am hoping for:

```
a   b   c   d
x1  12  15  0.2
x2  18  23  0.3
x3  11  40  1.1
x4  14  43  1
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the `full_join` is done using two columns `"a"` and `"d"` since they are the common columns between `n1` and `n2`. You might need to join only by `"a"` and then use `coalesce`.

```
library(dplyr)

full_join(n1, n2, by = "a") %>%
   mutate(d = coalesce(d.x, d.y)) %>%
   select(-d.x, -d.y)

#   a  b  c   d
#1 x1 12 15 0.2
#2 x2 18 23 0.3
#3 x3 11 40 1.1
#4 x4 14 43 1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

A base `R` option would be to match row and column names.

```
mrow = match(n1$a,n2$a)
mcol = match(colnames(n1),colnames(n2))

# [-1] removes the x1,x2 .. column
n1[!is.na(mrow),which(!is.na(mcol))[-1]] = n2[na.omit(mrow),na.omit(mcol)[-1]]
> n1
   a  b  c   d
1 x1 12 15 0.2
2 x2 18 23 0.3
3 x3 11 40 1.1
4 x4 14 43 1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this easily with `data.table` `join` without creating addtional columns and then modifying/removing

```
library(data.table)
setDT(n1)[n2, d := i.d, on = .(a)]
n1
#    a  b  c   d
#1: x1 12 15 0.2
#2: x2 18 23 0.3
#3: x3 11 40 1.1
#4: x4 14 43 1.0
```